# Objective C Polymorphism for a Game Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, polymorphism

My situation is that I have a few different mini-games in my app. The games are listed in a table view, and when one of them is selected I create the corresponding game object. I need the game objects to have a common parent class, so that I can do common things such as pausing and resuming.

I have a generic GameScene class which has a generic GameLayer property:

```
@interface GameScene : CCScene {

}

@property (nonatomic, strong) GameLayer* gameLayer;
```

However each child class of GameScene has it's own type of GameLayer. So for example the SuperMarioBros_GameScene has a SuperMarioBros_GameLayer. The problems arise when I initialize the SuperMarioBros_GameScene:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self = [super init])) {
        self.gameLayer = (SuperMarioBros_GameLayer*)[SuperMarioBros_GameLayer node];
        [self addChild: self.gameLayer];

        SuperMarioBros_InputLayer *inputLayer = [SuperMarioBros_InputLayer node];
        inputLayer.delegate = self.gameLayer; //ERROR (see below)
        [self addChild:inputLayer z:1 tag:2];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In general each game will also have an input layer, which will send UI messages to the gameLayer. I get this error:

```
Assigning to 'id <SuperMarioBros_FireDelegate> from incompatible type GameLayer*
```

I understand this is happening because SuperMarioBros_GameLayer implements `<SuperMarioBros_FireDelegate>`, but GameLayer doesn't.

So my question is how do I make the GameScene class hold a polymorphic property that can be any subclass of GameLayer? Keeping in mind that each type of GameLayer may implement different protocols based on their corresponding input layers? Or maybe there's a better way to go about this?

Again, the end goal is to be able to make a call from the main game controller such as

```
[currentGameScene pause];
```

which will in turn do something like:

```
[self.gameLayer pauseGameLoop];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  the implementation file of the `SuperMarioBros_GameScene` class, you can override the property declaration of the `gameLayer` property in a class extension:

```
@interface SuperMarioBros_GameScene ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SuperMarioBros_GameLayer *gameLayer;
@end
```

Then you should not get a compiler error anymore.

This will not create new getter or setter functions (these are still called in the superclass), and does not introduce a new instance variable as backing store. It only tells the compiler that `self.gameLayer` is an instance of the subclass in this implementation file.

Comment: I'm probably 75% clear on why this works, but it does, and it's easy.